# R: gnotebook tab starts on last tab not first

Tags: r, gwidgets

Im currently using these packages for my R programming GUI .

```
   library("gWidgetsRGtk2")
   library("RGtk2")
   library("gwidgets")
```

i created a window with tabs on the top of it , however whenever i start up , it starts up displaying on the last tab . I want it to be on the first tab any idea ?

```
#create Window
win <- gwindow("GUI WINDOW",height=400,weight=400)

#############################################################
# Create main tabs
#############################################################

nb = gnotebook(cont=win, tab.pos = 3)
grp_basic <- ggroup(cont=nb, label = "Basic Search")
grp_graphs <- ggroup(cont=nb, label = "Graphs")
grp_help <- ggroup(cont=nb, label = "Help")
```

Comment: You change the tab after you create the last page via `svalue(nb) <- 1`.

Answer (score 1):

As per your example you need to:

```
#create Window
win <- gwindow("GUI WINDOW",height=400,weight=400)

nb = gnotebook(cont=win, tab.pos = 3)
grp_basic <- ggroup(cont=nb, label = "Basic Search")
grp_graphs <- ggroup(cont=nb, label = "Graphs")
grp_help <- ggroup(cont=nb, label = "Help")
svalue(nb) <- 1  ##focus 1st tab
```